# Developed in windows - Can I host it in Linux?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

Hi I have developed online shop with ubercart in windows environment. Can I host it in Linux environmrnt? Is there any issues due to change in environment? Please provide your suggestion.

Technology - Drupal 6.x

Thanks

Comment: Without knowing exactly what is in your shop, I would just install whatever Linux OS you're thinking of porting it to on your own machine and trying it out. Many Linux OS's are free and easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Few things you need to know

1. Drupal is completely independent of the OS on which you run. (Except for few settings like mail integration and cron job).
2. By `windows environment` do you mean WAMP? If yes you need not make any changes. By `windows environment` if you mean Windows, IIS, SQL server then you need to make changes for cron jobs, clean urls and change the sql drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues to be concerned about when moving between hosts:

1. **Drupal dependencies**, and
2. **File permissions**

**For Drupal dependencies:** Make sure your Linux host meets the Drupal requirements in terms of memory, modules, etc. This is rather simple, just check Drupal's site.

**For the Permissions:** Things could work flawlessly after you upload the site and database... however it's more likely that you will have to check your file ownership and permissions.

In your Windows stack, the files are owned by a Windows user. When you upload them to your Linux stack, these need to be owned by a Linux user, but which?

If you're running SuExec on the Linux machine, the files will likely be owned by the same user you use for ssh or ftp access. If you're not using `SuExec`, the files will likely need to be owned by the apache user `www-data`.

Finally are the permissions to specific folders and the settings.php file. You Drupal status page will display errors if:

- your settings.php file is writable by anyone;
- if your file directory (where uploaded files are stored) is not writable or otherwise misconfigured;
- and if your tmp/ folder is also not writable or otherwise misconfigured.